# ionic cordova bulid android : No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved in the paths in .bash_profile

Comment: what is bash_profile? What you did I got same error don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Install Android Studio and start a new project. It will then download and install the SDK for you.

If you already have Android Studio installed go to the SDK manager and update the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Catalina, I am facing this problem in ionic 5 Cordova during an android build.

****How I solved this?****

- Set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment for Android(because ANDROID_HOME
  depricaite ).
- Set PATH environment for android build-tools
- Save changes and refresh terminal(or close and open terminal).
- Delete android platform.
- Instal again android cordova platfome using  *ionic cordova build
  android*.
- At end run command *ionic cordova build android*